# Unpacking ... in R

Tags: r

Frustrated to not be able to figure this out:

In an online course I'm doing, a code example was given as follows:

```
add_alpha_and_beta <- function(...){

    args <- list(...)
    print(args)

     alpha <- args[["alpha"]]
     beta  <- args[["beta"]]

     alpha + beta 
  }
```

This is meant to take a list with 2 named values alpha and beta, and add them together.  Simple.

However, the output I'm getting is:

```
[[1]]
alpha  beta 
    1     2 

numeric(0)
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: It's working for me, if I call the function as: `add_alpha_and_beta(alpha = 2, beta = 3)`. I.e. you need to name the arguments.

Comment: How are you running the function? As written, the function does not expect a list with 2 named components, but expects 2 named arguments, e.g. `add_alpha_and_beta(alpha=3,beta=4)`.

Comment: The section of the course was meant to be about how to use ... in function calls.  I called it by add_alpha_and_beta(c(alpha=1, beta=2)).  I also tried creating a variable ab <- c(alpha=1, beta=2) and calling it as add_alpha_and_beta(ab)

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be calling the function with a `list` or  a `vector` as its sole argument:

```
add_alpha_and_beta(list(alpha = 2, beta = 3))
add_alpha_and_beta(c(alpha = 2, beta = 3))
```

If so, you can unpack that by looking at the first item of `...`:

```
args = list(...)[[1]]
```

When calling the function without a list but instead directly with separate (named) parameters, your function works as advertised.

Comment: Thank you, Konrad , Gavin and bgoldst.  That explains it, I was creating a list and passing it, not passing multiple different arguments.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I see what you must be doing:

```
add_alpha_and_beta(list(alpha = 1, beta = 2))
```

I.e. you are passing in a single list with 2 components, the `alpha` and `beta`. The code doesn't account for this.

The way the function has been written, it expects you to call it as:

```
add_alpha_and_beta(alpha = 1, beta = 2)
```

Internally, you then capture the `...` in a list, which has names equal to the names of the keys in the key, value pairs you call ed the function with.

When you call the function like this:

```
add_alpha_and_beta(list(alpha = 1, beta = 2))
```

you are passing a single argument. `args` then is a list containing a list with two components:

```
Browse[2]> args
[[1]]
[[1]]$alpha
[1] 1

[[1]]$beta
[1] 2
```

As these are indexed directly as `args[["component"]]`, these both return `NULL`

```
Browse[2]> args[["alpha"]]
NULL
```

and `NULL + NULL` is a zero-length numeric:

```
Browse[2]> NULL + NULL
numeric(0)
```

Which is what you saw.

Without seeing the actual question/text it is impossible to say what is required, but if that was the code as given, you must be calling it in a way not anticipated nor expected by the course teacher. I'll add that it would be most natural to write and use R functions in this form

```
add_alpha_and_beta(alpha = 1, beta = 2)
```

rather than the way you have called the function. But if you want to do it that way, you'll need to add some indexing to get inside the first of the nested lists:

```
args <- list(...)[[1L]]
```

would work for example, but that would break the more natural usage. You'd complicate the code some more to handle both:

```
args <- list(...)
if (length(args) == 1L) {
  args <- args[[1L]]
  ## probably some error checking code here
}
....
```